# Conjugate a Turkish verb

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

## Input

- *verb*, a string that matches the regular expression `([a-pr-vyzıöüçğş]*[aeıioöuü][bcçdfgğhj-nprsştvyz]+|([a-pr-vyzıöüçğş]*[aeıioöuü]){2})(mak|mek)`
- *plural*, a truthy or falsy value
- *person*, an integer having value either 1, 2, or 3
- *tense*, an integer having value either 1, 2, or 3

## Output

The conjugated form of the Turkish verb *verb*, in *person*<sup>st/nd/rd</sup> person, plural if *plural* is `TRUE` and singular if it is not, in

- If *tense* is 1, the simple present;
- If *tense* is 2, the continuing present;
- If *tense* is 3, the future.

## Rules

Turkish verbs are conjugated in three elements, which are in order:

- The *stem*, formed by removing `mak` or `mek` from the end of the infinitive;
- The *sign of the tense*, which is:

  - For the simple present:

    > - *-r* if the stem ends in a vowel;
    > - *-ir* according to **vowel harmony rules** (see below) if the stem contains more than one syllable (i.e. vowel), or is from one of the following irregular verbs: *almak, bilmek, bulmak, durmak, gelmek, görmek, kalmak, olmak, ölmek, sanmak, vermek, varmak, vurmak*;
    > - *-er* according to **vowel harmony rules** if the stem contains one syllable and is not listed in the irregular verbs above.
  - For the continuing present, *-iyor*, where the *i* changes according to **vowel harmony rules**. Stems that end in a vowel drop this vowel before adding this suffix, whereupon the suffix harmonizes with the next-to-last vowel in the word (guaranteed to exist by the regular expression).
  - For the future:

    > - *-ecek* according to **vowel harmony rules** if the stem ends in a consonant;
    > - *-yecek* according to **vowel harmony rules** if the stem ends in a vowel.
- The *personal suffix* to indicate the performer of the action, in all cases according to **vowel harmony rules**:

  ```
      |Singular|Plural|
  |---|--------|------|
  |1st|    -im |   -iz|
  |2nd|   -sin |-siniz|
  |3rd| (none) |  -ler|
  ```

  The final *k* of the future tense becomes *ğ* before *-im* and *-iz*, so for example `(almak, TRUE, 1, 3)` would yield `alacağız`.

## Vowel harmony rules

Turkish vowels are divided into two groups: back (`a ı o u`) and front (`e i ö ü`) by where in the mouth they are pronounced. The suffixes of a word change vowels according to the vowels of the root.

All suffixes listed above that have *i* as a vowel instead use:

- *-ı* if the last vowel before the suffix is `ı` or `a` (both these vowels are back and unrounded);
- *-i* if the last vowel before the suffix is `i` or `e` (both these vowels are front and unrounded; note here Turkish's distinction between [dotted and dotless I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I));
- *-u* if the last vowel before the suffix is `u` or `o` (both these vowels are back and rounded); or
- *-ü* if the last vowel before the suffix is `ü` or `ö` (both these vowels are front and rounded).

Take careful note of the present continuous suffix *-iyor*. The `i` harmonizes, but the `o` does not change. The personal suffixes will thus harmonize with the `o`.

All the suffixes listed above that have *e* as a vowel instead use:

- *-e* if the last vowel before the suffix is a front vowel; or
- *-a* if the last vowel before the suffix is a back vowel.

## Irregular verbs

The verbs *gitmek*, *tatmak*, *ditmek*, *gütmek*, and *etmek* change the final `t` to a `d` before any endings that begin with a vowel (which includes all the endings in this challenge). Any verb that ends in *-etmek* likewise changes the `t` to a `d`, and appends *-er* for the simple present (though this is not so for the other verbs).

## Test cases

```
gütmek, FALSE, 1, 2 -> güdüyorum
almak, TRUE, 3, 3 -> alacaklar
boğmak, TRUE, 2, 1 -> boğarsınız
ölmek, FALSE, 3, 1 -> ölür
boyamak, TRUE, 1, 2 -> boyuyoruz
affetmek, FALSE, 2, 1 -> affedersin
söylemek, TRUE, 3, 1 -> söylerler
söylemek, FALSE, 3, 2 -> söylüyor
söylemek, FALSE, 1, 3 -> söyleyeceğim
```

Comment: Could you provide a test case for the `-etmek` rule?

Comment: @Arnauld Done. In doing so I discovered I made an error in the specification, which I have appended to the "irregular verbs" section.

Comment: This could do with a lot more test cases, since the spec is quite complex.

Comment: @Dave I added 3 more, which took me long enough on mobile. I'll add even more later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>466</s> <s>456</s> <s>451</s> 446 bytes

```
(v,p,w,t)=>(R=g=>g.exec(s),T=r=>s=s.slice(0,-1)+r,Z=s=>s.replace(/\d/g,c=>l=['ıuiü'[(n='aıoueiöü'.search(l))>>1],'ae'[n>>2]][c]),(s=v.slice(k=l=0,-3)).replace(/[aıoueiöü]/g,c=>(L=l,l=c,k++)),(R(/^(gi|ta|di|gü)t$/)||(R(/et$/)&&(k=1)))&&T`d`,((E=R(/[aıoueiöü]$/))&&t==2?(l=L,T``):s)+Z([(E?'':k<2&!R(/^((k?a|bi|bu|ge|o|ö)l)|dur|gör|san|v[aeu]r$/))+'r','0yor',(E?'y1c1':'1c1')+'ğkk'[--w]][t-1])+Z('0m|0z|s0n|s0n0z||l1r'.split`|`[w+w+p],t-2||(l='o')))
```

#### Ungofled and commented

```
// Parameters:
//   - 'v' = verb
//   - 'p' = plural flag
//   - 'w' = person
//   - 't' = tense
(v, p, w, t) => (
  // R() - Helper function to execute a regular expression on the stem.
  R = g => g.exec(s),

  // T() - Helper function to replace the last character of the stem with 'r'.
  T = r => s = s.slice(0, -1) + r,

  // Z() - Function that applies vowel harmony to the string 's', assuming
  //       '0' = 'i' and '1' = 'e' and using the last encountered vowel 'l'.
  Z = s => s.replace(
    /\d/g,
    c => l = [
      'ıuiü' [(n = 'aıoueiöü'.search(l)) >> 1],
      'ae' [n >> 2]
    ][c]
  ),

  // Computes:
  //   - 's' = stem
  //   - 'k' = number of vowels in stem
  //   - 'l' = last vowel in stem
  //   - 'L' = penultimate vowel in stem
  (s = v.slice(k = l = 0, -3)).replace(/[aıoueiöü]/g, c => (L = l, l = c, k++)),

  // Applies ending 't' => 'd' for irregular verbs and those ending in -et(mek).
  (R(/^(gi|ta|di|gü)t$/) || (R(/et$/) && (k = 1))) && T `d`,

  // Computes 'E' = truthy value if the stem ends in a vowel.
  // If 'E' is truthy and the tense is the continuing present, drops this vowel.
  ((E = R(/[aıoueiöü]$/)) && t == 2 ? (l = L, T ``) : s) +

  // Appends sign of tense with vowel harmony.
  Z([
    // t = 1: simple present -> either '-er', '-ir' or '-r'
    (E ? '' : k < 2 & !R(/^((k?a|bi|bu|ge|o|ö)l)|dur|gör|san|v[aeu]r$/) + 'r',

    // t = 2: continuing present -> always '-iyor'
    '0yor',

    // t = 3: future -> either '-yecek', '-ecek', '-yeceğ' or '-eceğ'
    (E ? 'y1c1' : '1c1') + 'ğkk' [--w]
  ][t - 1]) +

  // Appends personal suffix with vowel harmony,
  // forcing last vowel to 'o' for continuing present.
  Z(
    '0m|0z|s0n|s0n0z||l1r'.split `|` [w + w + p],
    t - 2 || (l = 'o')
  )
)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =
(v,p,w,t)=>(R=g=>g.exec(s),T=r=>s=s.slice(0,-1)+r,Z=s=>s.replace(/\d/g,c=>l=['ıuiü'[(n='aıoueiöü'.search(l))>>1],'ae'[n>>2]][c]),(s=v.slice(k=l=0,-3)).replace(/[aıoueiöü]/g,c=>(L=l,l=c,k++)),(R(/^(gi|ta|di|gü)t$/)||(R(/et$/)&&(k=1)))&&T`d`,((E=R(/[aıoueiöü]$/))&&t==2?(l=L,T``):s)+Z([(E?'':k<2&!R(/^((k?a|bi|bu|ge|o|ö)l)|dur|gör|san|v[aeu]r$/))+'r','0yor',(E?'y1c1':'1c1')+'ğkk'[--w]][t-1])+Z('0m|0z|s0n|s0n0z||l1r'.split`|`[w+w+p],t-2||(l='o')))

console.log(f("gütmek", false, 1, 2));    // -> güdüyorum
console.log(f("almak", true, 3, 3));      // -> alacaklar
console.log(f("boğmak", true, 2, 1));     // -> boğarsınız
console.log(f("ölmek", false, 3, 1));     // -> ölür
console.log(f("boyamak", true, 1, 2));    // -> boyuyoruz
console.log(f("affetmek", false, 2, 1));  // -> affedersin
console.log(f("söylemek", true, 3, 1));   // -> söylerler
console.log(f("söylemek", false, 3, 2));  // -> söylüyor
console.log(f("söylemek", false, 1, 3));  // -> söyleyeceğim
```

Comment: Does this account for the `d`-mutation on all verbs ending in *-etmek*? I don't know JavaScript but from what I can gather it looks like it's just lumped in with the others.

Comment: @EMBLEM - This should be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## sed, 583 bytes

```sh
sed -E 's/^((bul|dur|k?al|ol|san|v[au]r)ma|(bil|gel|gör|öl|ver)me)k( . .) 1/\2\3Ir\4/;s/etmek( . .) 1/edEr\1/;s/etmek /ed /;s/^((ta)tma|([dg]i|gü)tme)k /\2\3d /;s/m[ae]k / /;s/([aıoueiöüEI])/V\1/g;s/(V.)( . .) 1/\1r\2/;s/(V.+V.+)( . .) 1/\1VIr\2/;s/( . .) 1/VEr\1/;s/(V.)?( . .) 2/VIyVor\2/;s/(V.)( . . 3)/\1y\2/;s/( . .) 3/VEcVEk\1/;s/k( . 1)/ğ\1/;s/ 0 1/VIm/;s/ 1 1/VIz/;s/ 0 2/sVIn/;s/ 1 2/sVInVIz/;s/ 0 3//;s/ 1 3/lVEr/;:l
s/([ıa][^V]*V)I/\1ı/;s/([ie][^V]*V)I/\1i/;s/([uo][^V]*V)I/\1u/;s/([üö][^V]*V)I/\1ü/;s/([aıou][^V]*V)E/\1a/;s/(V[^aEI][^V]*V)E/\1e/;t l
s/V//g'
```

Like my [answer to the closely-related Dactylic Hexameter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92151/8927) question, this is really just translating the rules as given into regular expressions.

#### Usage:

Takes input in the form:

```
word [01] [123] [123]
```

So the test cases are:

```sh
printf 'gütmek 0 1 2
almak 1 3 3
boğmak 1 2 1
ölmek 0 3 1
boyamak 1 1 2
affetmek 0 2 1
söylemek 1 3 1
söylemek 0 3 2
söylemek 0 1 3' | sed -E '<...>';
```

#### Breakdown:

```sh
sed -E "
# special cases for simple present tense
 s/^((bul|dur|k?al|ol|san|v[au]r)ma|(bil|gel|gör|öl|ver)me)k( . .) 1/\2\3Ir\4/;

# stemming
# always uses -er rule if simple present
 s/etmek( . .) 1/edEr\1/;
 s/etmek /ed /;
 s/^((ta)tma|([dg]i|gü)tme)k /\2\3d /;
 s/m[ae]k / /;

# mark vowels for easier expressions later
 s/([aıoueiöüEI])/V\1/g;

# simple present
 s/(V.)( . .) 1/\1r\2/;
 s/(V.+V.+)( . .) 1/\1VIr\2/;
 s/( . .) 1/VEr\1/;

# continuing present
 s/(V.)?( . .) 2/VIyVor\2/;

# future
 s/(V.)( . . 3)/\1y\2/;
 s/( . .) 3/VEcVEk\1/;

# personal suffix
 s/k( . 1)/ğ\1/;
 s/ 0 1/VIm/;
 s/ 1 1/VIz/;
 s/ 0 2/sVIn/;
 s/ 1 2/sVInVIz/;
 s/ 0 3//;
 s/ 1 3/lVEr/;

# vowel harmony
 :l
 s/([ıa][^V]*V)I/\1ı/;
 s/([ie][^V]*V)I/\1i/;
 s/([uo][^V]*V)I/\1u/;
 s/([üö][^V]*V)I/\1ü/;

 s/([aıou][^V]*V)E/\1a/;
 s/(V[^aEI][^V]*V)E/\1e/;
# keep looping until all vowels are known
 t l

# unmark vowels
 s/V//g
"
```

#### Results for test cases:

```
güdüyorum
alacaklar
boğarsınız
ölür
boyuyoruz
affedersin
söylerler
söylüyor
söyleyeceğim
```

Comment: You are correct about affedersin. I switched pronouns several times while writing that

Comment: Take note of case 2; it should be alacak**lar**, not ler.

Comment: @EMBLEM fixed; cost me 2 more bytes though (but what's 2 bytes in 600?)

Comment: You can remove `sed -E ''`, since you specified sed as being the language and not bash, so consider the script as sed source code. You could then run it like: `printf ...|sed -Ef filename`, adding 1 byte more for the E flag, saving 8 bytes in the end. Btw, never knew until today that -E is equivalent to -r!